# Newton's $3^{rd}$ Law of motion

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

If we hit someone, we don't feel that much pain as compared to the one whom we hit. According to Newton's $3^{rd}$ Law of motion, every action has an equal and opposite reaction. Why is it not applicable here? Or is it applicable but in some other way?

Comment: This question is more opinion based than fact based.  People have broken their hands hitting other people.  MMA fighters have broken the lower leg in half through the bone throwing kicks at other fighters in the ring.  It's just simply not true to start.

Comment: Pain is not a unit of measure, every person reacts differently to pain.

Comment: Although I wish not to condone self-violence (so think of this as a thought-experiment), consider hitting yourself in the head and then hitting yourself fist-to-fist. That experiment may reveal the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your fist receives the same impulse (force x time) as whatever it hits.

The reason someone's nose may *feel* it more than your fist is because noses and fists aren't built the same.  This is therefore a biology question, once the physics has confirmed that the same impulse is received.

Stop and actually *Think* about it.  Even ignoring the fist part of a punch, clearly the same punch received by different parts of your body will feel differently.  This really should have been obvious.